# Google Sheets - Add range of dates based on string

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

Is it possible in Google sheets to have a formula which looks at a certain date and creates a range of dates based on it?

I have this google sheet:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ccLwh_ExEtE2zxYUor9hxi1hMyADQtuUgyCyOKASxIk

Is it possible to have formulas in the left column rows to just look at the date string "august" and automatically fill in the dates down each row? Preferably with this format I have in this sheet? Like:

monday

---

1

---

Tuesday

---

2

---

Wednesday

---

3

I know it's possible to format a date so it ways monday 1 e.g, but for some reason, google sheets doesn't text wrap dates and I want a line break between the day and number, if possible.

Any help truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since tagged [excel-formula]:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(1&"August"&2016)+ROW()-1),"dddd")&CHAR(10)&ROW()
```

in Row1 and copied down to suit should work. (For just Google Sheets this Q probably belongs on Web Applications.)

The month selection is hard-coded into the formula but could be parameterized.